# RxJava - Repeat API calls until all item returned

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, retrofit2, reactivex

I have an API call that returns list of items by page. I use retrofit to implement and the interface is:

```
Observable<QueryResult> queryData(@Body QueryParams params);
```

The QueryParams and QueryResult is define as:

```
class QueryParams {
    int pageIndex, pageSize; // for pagination;
    ... // other query criteria
}

class QueryResult {
    int pageIndex, pageSize;
    int totalCount; // This is the total data size which is used to know if there are still data to retreat.
    ... // List of data returned by page;
}
```

And I use this code to get the first page of 100 data item:

```
params.pageIndex = 1;
params.pageSize = 100;
queryData(params).subscribe(...);
```

The API is designed as to get the data list page by page so I could efficiently response to the UI representation.

Somehow, in some cases, I need to get all the data at once and process with some tasks before representing to UI. With the interface designed like this, I have to call the queryData() several times till all the data fetched or at least twice (the first one to get the totalCount and pass it to pageSize for the second call).

So, my question is how do I do it with RxJava manners chaining API calls to get all the data?

Thanks in advance.

**Update** A solution from @Abu

```
Observable<QueryResult> query(final QueryParams params) {
    return queryData(params)
            .concatMap(new Func1<QueryResult, Observable<QueryResult>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<QueryResult> call(final QueryResult result) {
                    int retrievedCount = result.getPageSize() * (result.getPageIndex() - 1) + result.resultList.size();
                    if (retrievedCount >= result.getCount()) {
                        return Observable.just(result);
                    }

                    QueryParams nextParams = params.clone();
                    nextParams.setPageIndex(results.getPageIndex() + 1);
                    return query(nextParams).map(new Func1<QueryResult, QueryResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public QueryResult call(QueryResult nextResult) {
                            nextResult.resultList.addAll(result.resultList);
                            return nextResult;
                        }
                    });
                }
}
```

Comment: Personally I believe that, this should be done by server. Instead of making chain of call, you perfrom certain mechanism by the server so that it will return all the data instead of chunks. For example pass pagesize -1 to get all the data.

Comment: Take a look at RxJava `Zip` operator

Comment: @Wizard Yes, I can't agree with you more. It is that in the real world, somethings I just can't touch, like the secret hiding behind the server. Still thanks for your advice, I will try to ask for help from server side.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I check the use of Zip. It seems that it can wait for two operating results and emit at once. The assumption is that these two operations are not related and can be executed in parallel. But in my case, I have to at least call the API once to get the total count before preceding further.

Comment: @Pai-HsiangHuang perhaps you can use something like `flatMap` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may be to do it recursively with `concatMap` and `concatWith` operator.

Here is a sample code.

```
    private Observable<List<Integer>> getResponse(final int index) {



    return getData(index)
            .concatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, ObservableSource<? extends List<Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<? extends List<Integer>> apply(List<Integer> integers) throws Exception {

                    if (index == 10) {
                        return Observable.just(integers);
                    }else {
                        return Observable.just(integers)
                                .concatWith(getResponse(index + 1));
                    }
                }
            });
   }


   private Observable<List<Integer>> getData(int index){

      List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          dataList.add(index*10 + i);
      }

      return Observable.just(dataList);

   }
```

**Usage:**

```
        getResponse(1)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Integer> integers) throws Exception {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data: " + Arrays.toString(integers.toArray()));
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

This will give you all data recursively in a order. You will get data for first index 1 , them index 2 , .......

If there is a better solution i am waiting to see it.

**Edit:**

To get complete list of data use can update you code this way:

```
    private Observable<List<Integer>> getResponse(final int index) {

    return getData(index)
            .concatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, ObservableSource<? extends List<Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<? extends List<Integer>> apply(final List<Integer> integerList) throws Exception {

                    if (index < 9){
                        return getResponse(index+1)
                                .map(new Function<List<Integer>, List<Integer>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public List<Integer> apply(List<Integer> integers) throws Exception {
                                        integers.addAll(integerList);
                                        return integers;
                                    }
                                });
                    }else {
                        return Observable.just(integerList);
                    }

                }
            });
}


private Observable<List<Integer>> getData(int index){

    Util.printThreadInfo(index);

    final List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dataList.add(index*10 + i);
    }

    return Observable.just(dataList);

}
```

Usage:

```
        Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends List<Integer>>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<? extends List<Integer>> call() throws Exception {
            return getResponse(1);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Integer> integers) throws Exception {
                    Collections.sort(integers);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data: " + Arrays.toString(integers.toArray()));
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

This will give you complete data at once.

**I think you shouldn't get all data this way because if your page size is 100 you are crating 100 network call. You api should give you all data for a single call.**

I just update my answer to show how this can be done.

Comment: Tried your solution. And it works. The use of concatMap and concatWith returns data page by page. But, because I have to sort the data list before present it, I will have to wait all the data returned before the sorting. Is there a manner to retrieve all the data at once? Thanks.

Comment: Tried and it works. Although it seems like an over kill for trying to workaround a problem like this. Anyway, I will update the post according to you solution for reference. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is not recommended solution. Your api should return all data if you need.